# How to create the Navigation Drawer from scratch, using the AndroidX dependencies

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I've found plenty that work for pre Android X but can't find a decent tutorial for post Android X. Would really appreciate a run down on how to make one or just a link to a really good tutorial. I realize this is pretty openended, and I would just use the inbuilt navigation drawer, but I really want to understand it inside and out.

Comment: There's not much "inside-out" to it. It's three things: the `<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>` and two `<View>`s inside it; the first one being the content, the second being the drawer. Those two inside `View`s can be pretty much anything you want. If you're specifically wanting a tutorial on how to create the Navigation Drawer template in Android Studio from scratch, that might be a little too broad for Stack Overflow, and asking for links to off-site ones is off-topic.

Comment: I would also mention that you could just look at the code and layouts that are generated by that template. It's really not terribly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have migrated the project to Android. If you didnt you will find a lots of tutorials online. Once you do . when creating a new activity make sure you select Navigation Drawer activity and thats it. your navigation drawer will be with android x dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     android:id="@+id/navigation"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     android:background="@color/white"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

              <include layout="@layout/navigation_items" />

   </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```